# angularJS attribute based directive - pass isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I have written directives before that have an isolated scope but they are element directives

If i write a directive that is attribute based, how can i pass the isolated scope to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in exactly the same way as you did with element directive, i.e. attach further attributes that pass in the properties to the isolated scope.

**HTML:**

```
<div greeting-directive my-greeting="'hello'" greet-who="'world'"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("greetingDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myGreeting: "=",
            greetWho : "=" 
        },
        template: '<p>{{ myGreeting }}, {{ greetWho }}</p>'
    }
});
```

**[Sample Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/VDG9VzadVrQKkDg57gSe?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to isolate scope for Element directives. Consider this example:

```
myApp.directive('test', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {test: '='},
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('test', function () {
            console.log(scope.test)
        });
    }
};
});
```

I'm using the direcitve name as a scope variable.

```
<div test="ctrl.val">some stuff</div>
```

However if I didn't want to leverage the directive name like this:

```
myApp.directive('notTest', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {test: '='},
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('test', function () {
            console.log(scope.test)
        });
    }
};
});
```

Then html might look like this:

```
<div not-test test="ctrl.val">some stuff</div>
```